# Hover background not showing correctly?

Tags: html, css, menu, hover

I want to achieve this: 
[image]

This is what I achieved: [LINK](http://shrineweb.in/other-files/other/showyourskills-responsive-certsplan2/index.html)

When you hover over the navigation links, a white background with blue border in bottom should appear. Its not appearing right. Why is that happening?

Markup:

```
<header>
    <div>
        <h1>CertsPlan</h1>
        <section>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">+ All Vendors</a></li>
                <li>
                    <article id="header-cart">
                        <img src="img/cart-icon.png" alt="Cart Icon"> 000
                    </article>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <article id="header-search">
                            <form action="#">
                              <input type="text" name="search" value="Exam Code">
                            </form>
                      </article>
                </li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Sign In/Register</a></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html"><img src="img/home.png" alt="Home Icon"></a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Bundle</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Faqs</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
/* Global Styles */
body {
    border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
    background: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    color: #57616a;
}

p {
    margin: 5px 0;
    line-height: 25px;
}

strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* Section Styles */

/* Header */
header {
    width:auto;
    margin: 2 auto 0 auto;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border-bottom: solid 5px #dedede;
}

header div {
    width:auto;
    max-width:1040px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

header h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #2a323a;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    float:left;
}


/* Navigation */
nav {
    float:right;
    margin:none;
}

header ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

nav ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 38px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

nav ul li a {
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #2a323a;
  padding: 38px 20px 35px 20px;
  text-decoration:none;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: solid 5px #00acdd;
}

ul li a:active {
    background-color: #ffffff; 
    border-bottom: solid 5px #00acdd !important;
}

/* Header top right area */

header section {
    float:right;
}

header section li {
    display:block;
    float:right;
    margin: 37px 0px 28px 7px;
}

header section a {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #31bbe2;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `overflow: hidden` on two parent elements, which hides everything between the borders: (blue color on the image)
 [image]
Your blue border on the `a` tag was beyond the parent's border.

Here's the solution:

1. should delete `overflow: hidden` from `header div`, and add `min-height: 89px`.
2. Delete `overflow: hidden` from `header ul` too.
3. in `nav ul li a` change the `padding` to: `38px 20px 33px`.

That's all.

***EDIT:***

If you want to make it work even when you resize the browser than add a `div` right after `nav` like so:

```
<nav>
   [...]
</nav>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Style's for the `clear` div:

```
.clear {
   clear: both;
   display: table;
}
```

Comment: Here is a working example of this: [Code-Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GdpAs/).

Note: This doesn't work if the browser is resized.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you! I have updated result on my link.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your css class

```
nav ul li a
{
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #2a323a;
    padding: 38px 20px 30px 20px;  // This is where you are wrong
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 93px;
}
```

This is because you have set too much padding at bottom which disallow border to appear

It will work

Comment: Blue border appears now but not in sync. I have updated on my link, please check.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    /* Global Styles */
body
{
    border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
    background: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    color: #57616a;}

p
{
    margin: 5px 0;
    line-height: 25px;}

strong
{
    font-weight: bold;}

/* Section Styles */

/* Header */
header
{
    width:auto;
    margin: 2 auto 0 auto;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border-bottom: solid 5px #dedede;
     height: 93px;
}

header div {
    width:auto;
    max-width:60%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

header h1
{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #2a323a;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    float:left;
}


/* Navigation */
nav {
    float:right;
    margin:none;
}

header ul
{
list-style:none;
margin: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}

nav ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 38px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

nav ul li a {
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #2a323a;
  padding: 38px 20px 35px 20px;
  text-decoration:none;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: solid 8px #00acdd;
}

ul li a:active {background-color: #ffffff; border-bottom: solid 5px #00acdd !important;}

/* Header top right area */

header section {
    float:right;
}

header section li {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin: 37px 0px 28px 7px;
}

header section a {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #31bbe2;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
</style>
<header>
    <div>
        <h1>CertsPlan</h1>
        <section>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">+ All Vendors</a></li>

                <li>
                    <article id="header-search">
                            <form action="#">
                              <input type="text" name="search" value="Exam Code">
                            </form>
                      </article>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <article id="header-cart">
                        <img src="img/cart-icon.png" alt="Cart Icon"> 000
                    </article>
                </li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Sign In/Register</a></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html"><img src="img/home.png" alt="Home Icon"></a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Bundle</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Faqs</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: HTML I changed the Li order

Comment: header div {
    width:auto;
    max-width:60%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

Comment: header section li {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin: 37px 0px 28px 7px;
}